# using relative paths without packages

Tags: python-3.x

Several questions have been posted on the topic of relative paths in python, and it looks like this continues to be a fairly confusing topic, and no final word mentioned on it. I had found the most illustrative example in https://github.com/wweiradio/pkg-relative-import

However, when I made a few changes to those files, I ended up again with some error messages. After some amount of debugging, I came up with the following files and directory structure which works. (In the hierarchy mentioned below, I have mentioned the imports in each file, and which imports work and which dont.)

NOTE: (1) the code works, whether or not __init__.py files exist. So I have deleted all those files. (2) the files mentioned contain only the mentioned import lines, and maybe some print statements, and nothing else.

I run the code as:

```
cd top_level; python3 start1.py --> this works
cd top_level/src; python3 start2.py --> this does not work, as expected
```

I learnt the following lessons from this exercise:

(1) no relative paths on the invocation directory is allowed, or anywhere outside it.

(2) any further imports should be explicitly relative (eg .sub3, and not sub3),
  or absolute with reference to the top level (eg src.sub2.sub3)

(3) relative paths have nothing to do with packages, nor the presence or absence of __init__.py.
  eg, in the below code I have deleted all **init**.py, and it still works

(4) current dir is ., its parent is .., its grandparent is ..., etc

Can you confirm if these lessons are correct, and are there some other factors that I need to remember while using relative paths?

directory structure:

```
- top_level/
    - top.py
    - start1.py --> import src.sub.relative
    - src/
        - parent.py
        - start2.py --> import sub.relative
        - sub/
            - relative.py --> from .. import parent
                              from ..sub2 import relative2
                              # these imports give error if start2.py is called
                              # this is understood, so we call only start1.py
        - sub2/
            - relative2.py --> import top
                               from .. import parent
                               #from sub3 import relative3 # --> doesnt work
                               from .sub3 import relative3 # --> works
                               from src.sub2.sub3 import relative3 # --> works
                               #import sub3.relative3 # --> doesnt work
                               import src.sub2.sub3.relative3 # --> works
            - sub3/
                - relative3.py --> import top
                                   from ... import parent
```

Comment: There is ONLY ONE rule when it comes to `python imports`. You have to import things w.r.t. the directory that contains your application script. Everything in your entire codebase regardless of how huge that is, has to be imported correctly w.r.t. the directory where you fire your invocation script from. I had learnt this the hard way.

Comment: Yes but that is using the absolute path wrt the top. I was referring to relative paths wrt any current directory.

Comment: Yeah right. Your findings are correct in that case. What I meant to suggest is that you should try and avoid relative imports and provide absolute paths. Will save you a lot of trouble.